# How to insert reference field into Webflow API

Tags: postman, webflow

I have two collections: 1. Properties 2.Locations

Properties as a reference field called suburb which references locations collection.

How do I insert data into properties by referencing the locations collection?

My code (JSON) so far below which throws an error, trying on Postman first

```json
{
  "fields": {
    "name": "Housing Title",
    "description": "This will be the descriptiont that goes in",
    "category-listing": "Commercial Sale",
    "suburb-2": {
      "_id": "6417cdcf7b8e01699f338c6a",
      "collection": "6417cdcf7b8e01699f338c6a"
    },
    "state": "WA",
    "postcode": "6027",
    "build-area": "100m2",
    "advertised-listing-price": "$13,500 P.A. + OUTGOINGS + GST",
    "listing-price": "13000",
    "listing-category": "For Lease",
    "property-type": "Industrial/Warehouse",
    "longitude": "115.75085643394478",
     "latitude": "-31.67810959969579",
     "_archived": false,
    "_draft": false  
  }
}
```

This is the error:

```json
"msg": "Validation Failure",
    "code": 400,
    "name": "ValidationError",
    "path": "/collections/64c207376c291b57a5b5405e/items",
    "err": "ValidationError: Validation Failure",
    "problems": [
        "Field 'suburb-2': Expected value to be an ItemRef: {\n  _id: '6417cdcf7b8e01699f338c6a',\n  collection: '6417cdcf7b8e01699f338c6a'\n}"
    ],
    "problem_data": [
        {
            "slug": "suburb-2",
            "msg": "Expected value to be an ItemRef",
            "value": "{\n  _id: '6417cdcf7b8e01699f338c6a',\n  collection: '6417cdcf7b8e01699f338c6a'\n}"
        }
    ],
    "extensions": {
        "input": {
            "collection_id": {},
            "item_id": null,
            "target": "staging",
            "mode": "staging",
            "need_staging": true,
            "need_live": false,
            "need_collections": false,
            "need_staging_draft": false,
            "isPatchMode": false,
            "isSilentMode": false,
            "skipInvalidFiles": false
        },
        "meta": {
            "authType": "oauth_user",
            "userId": {}
        }
    }
}
```